# Multithreading Starting all Threads at once Dynamically

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, dynamic-programming

**my goal is to**

- Check thread if they are something ( initiallized , alive, On, what ever)
- If they are not add as many threads as needed ( up to 5 ) until all threads are started
- If all threads are started , recheck w/o loosing a `count` in `i-loop`
- *Additionally this is **hard** because of how to remove threads from the Dictionary when all threads are using the same sub*

> **The following code shows everything , the AllOtherThreads sub is simply**

```
Sub AllOtherThreads(ByVal i As Integer)
    For z = 0 To 500
        For q = 0 To 500
            For w = 0 To 500
                SomethingInvoked_Invoke(i, z, qt, wt)
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

> **Main Code**

```
    For i = 0 To 500
    Recheck:
        For izt = 0 To 2
            If dictThread.Values(izt) Is Nothing Then
                dictThread.Add("Thread" & izt.ToString, New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf AllOtherThreads)))
                dictThread.Values(izt).Start(i)
                GoTo nexti
            ElseIf dictThread.Values(izt).IsAlive = False Then

                dictThread.Remove(dictThread.Keys(izt))
```

**In the following line is where the error occurs `Thread is running or terminated; it cannot restart.`**

```
                dictThread.Values(izt).Start(i)
                GoTo nexti
            End If
        Next
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        GoTo Recheck
    nexti:
    Next
```

Comment: What is the question you would like answered? Are you asking how to start multiple threads without hardcoding them?

Comment: i will point to them better

Comment: You only need to start the thread once, which you are doing when you create it. Threads cannot be restarted, so if you want to run that code again, you will need to create a new thread.

Comment: Right but my threads are created in a Dictionary, therefore must be removed and re-added to the Thread Dictionary right? Therefore Restarting them?

Comment: Yes. You can use the `Dictionary.Remove("Key")` method to remove items from the dictionary.

Comment: in the above code, thats what i'm doing... is it not?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36572/discussion-between-camerondm9-and-don-thomas-boyle)

Comment: @camerondm9 Thanks fixed it with your comments the code to use was `Dim values As String = dictThread.Keys(izt) 'grab old key
                    dictThread.Remove(dictThread.Keys(izt))     'remove key
                    dictThread.Add(values, New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf AllOtherThreads))) 'add new (old) key
                    dictThread.Values(izt).Start(i)             'start key` thats from start - end of the dictionary .isalive 'if-else' section of the code, formulate an answer so I can mark it right-answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads cannot be restarted. If you need to run that code again, create a new thread.
In your case, you probably want to remove the old entry from the dictionary, and then recreate it:

```
For i = 0 To 500
Recheck:
    For izt = 0 To 2
        If dictThread.Values(izt) Is Nothing Then
            dictThread.Add("Thread" & izt.ToString, New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf AllOtherThreads)))
            dictThread.Values(izt).Start(i)
            GoTo nexti
        ElseIf dictThread.Values(izt).IsAlive = False Then
            Dim values As String = dictThread.Keys(izt)
            'Remove old thread
            dictThread.Remove(values)
            'Create new thread
            dictThread.Add(values, New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf AllOtherThreads)))
            'Start new thread
            dictThread.Values(izt).Start(i)
            GoTo nexti
        End If
    Next
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    GoTo Recheck
nexti:
Next
```